# Updating datagridview cell values and displaying on datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2005

I am trying to make a datagridview in visual studio 2005 in c# and .net in which i have defined the number of rows and columns (like 2*2) I want to add values to these cells .How can i add values to these cells and continuously update these values.
I used `random` function to update but for that i have to click on button everytime i want to update , so i want to know if there is a way so that i can update it automatically but not from database but from random() function.

Where can i study for these thing , tell me if there is use of threading to that too.

Comment: You can maybe use a timer to run your generation of random numbers at an interval.

Comment: I used timer, but still I want to know how to do it by the use of thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do it, using `Threading`, `Timer` (if it is WinForms, but I'm assuming it is) or `BackgrounWorker`. In my opinion the best way to do that would be Timer.

You use `Timer` like this:

```
    private void CreateTimer()
    {
        var t = new Timer();
        t.Interval = 1000; //how often update timer (in ms)
        t.Tick += new EventHandler(Tick);
        t.Start();
    }

    private void Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //logic to update your data grid view.
    }
```

Comment: thanks i have implemented it successfully. still i want to know how can i do it with the help of thread , any documentations , any website for particular thing .thanks